# Input type="time" not working properly with Katalon Recorder

Tags: katalon-recorder

Initially, I can't make the Katalon Recording (Edge Extension) work with input type time with its datalist selection. The problem with this is that the Katalon Recording can't specifically click the clock icon hence it can't open the list of hours.

Finally, I tried to use type instead of click but unfortunately can't make it work. The values I put seem not to be going to the website.

Update: I added a combination of click + type still not works. I found out that it does not click the input field at all. It does nothing and just skips the input.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why type and click are not working. My workaround here is to use `setText` command to input the value for time.